# Cached/offline maps for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, caching, maps, offline, openstreetmap

I'd like to use use maps in my application, so that there will be as less as possible traffic. Perfect solution would be caching of map slices. I know it's not possible with google maps (license). I took a look on OpenStreetMaps and it seems as good solution. The next: SDK. The only one I've found is from CloudMade. The problem is, I found no related API methods for caching/offline calls.
Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: You have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067590/how-to-use-offline-cloudmade-maps-in-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find more information on the [Route-Me project Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/w/list).