# IOS Text To Speech Conversion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text to speech on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

i am new to `tts` technology in ios.
Can somebody please tell me the effective `TTS` Library that support the common language localization for all languages , i tried `ispeech`, `flite`, `OpenEar` etc ,, but is there any other options , that are more effective with good sound quality. 
Thanks

Comment: what happen...is your problem solved?

Comment: what happen...why did you remove your acceptance from my answer???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

1. [Google TTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923974/iphone-sdk-google-tts-and-encoding)
2. [Dragon](http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon/index.htm)
3. [Acapela](http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com/)
4. [Ivona](http://developer.ivona.com/)
5. [Neo Speech](http://www.neospeech.com/tts-engine.aspx)

TTS Sample App [here](https://github.com/jonbarlo/iPhoneTTSSampleApp) (Objective-C)

Here is a [sample code](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src) of TTS (not working)

**Note:**
I have no personal experience with the above mentioned TTS libraries except Dragon. It is a nice TTS library with Good Sound quality.

Comment: @SachinSiwal: with pleasure dude :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Midhun I am trying to implement Map in IOS, that works in offline mode , do you have any idea regarding it , how to do it

Comment: @SachinSiwal: I have no idea about it,please check these links http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/10/05/apples-new-ios-6-maps-support-automatic-offline-use-for-a-wide-area,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440845/cached-offline-maps-for-iphone,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193475/offline-map-from-sdk

Comment: Here you can find a workind TTS sample app for iOS ---> https://github.com/jonbarlo/iPhoneTTSSampleApp