# How to integrate SIRI in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, siri

I am developing an iPad app. I want to integrate SIRI functionality in it.

So, please guide me to work on this. Actually I don't know how to  start.

Thanks,

Cp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Till now apple not released siri's api for third party applications.

If you are looking for text-to-speech, speech-to-text functionality. There are alot of external api's like:

1. [Nuance - Dragon](http://www.nuance.com/index.htm)
2. [ispeech](http://www.ispeech.org/)
3. [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)

And a lot of other api's.

OpenEars is a opensource offline api, and the other two are paid and online.

Comment: For more text-to-speech libraries check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860091/ios-text-to-speech-conversion/13860374#13860374