# Is it possible to use siri in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, siri

I want to develop an iPhone/iPad app with siri support.Is it really possible ? Can anybody please help me

Comment: Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965686/how-to-integrate-siri-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 5):

Previous Answer : You can't access Siri features, Apple didn't provide public API for Siri :-S .

The best APIs I've seen is the [Openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
the tutorials for openears are available here [Tutorials](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/)

and second one is [Dragon Mobile SDK](http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home)

New Answer as per update in SDK :
Now Siri is officially available.

Comment: Siri is now available for public for iOS 10 and above

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Siri integration in iOS apps, the iOS 10 states that the "Siri" support should only be added if an app implements one of the following types of services:

- Audio or video calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Searching photos
- Workouts
- Ride booking

The apps integrate with Siri through these specific domains only (restriction by Apple), which define categories of behaviors that an app can support.

By limiting the scope of Siri in iOS 10, Apple has standardized the integration.