# How to analyse particular sound in iOS

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

I want to develop an app which will respond or take an action when user say 'hello'.I want my app to be able to respond when i say particular word.How can i do that? Can anyone suggest me by code?Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer, but I would look for a way to integrate Siri's technology.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to integrate Siri. But see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13860091/1970843

Comment: @GabrielF - your link is for a question regarding Text To Speech. He's asking for the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some libraries available to work with voice recognization, 
apparently the most used is [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/).

But there are others as has been said in this topic:
[How to use Speech Recognition inside the iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812399/how-to-use-speech-recognition-inside-the-ios-sdk)